# Early 90s book series: bicycle in 13th(?) gear travels to other worlds

Tags: story-identification

Okay, my memory of this is pretty vague. 
A guy encounters a funny little man that gives his bicycle the ability to travel to other worlds. He does this by adding an extra gear to the man's 12(?) speed. When the bike was travelling at a certain speed he would be able to shift into this extra gear and the bike would be teleported to a sort of subspace corridor. 
The corridor was endless and had shapes all along the walls that were gateways to other worlds. The protagonist called some of them "Bart Simpson heads", because the outline of them was similar.
He occasionally encountered other beings there, riding odd vehicles.

The books (I read two, there may have been more) were about the strange adventures he had visiting some of the worlds.
I seem to remember one of the books being called, "The 13th Gear", but Google had nothing for me and neither did any of the sci-fi book databases I tried.

Comment: Could you edit this question so the title is more specific?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the [*Bicycling Through Space and Time*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?29052) series by [Mike Sirota](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1573):

[*Bicycling Through Space and Time*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4444) (1991)
[*The Ultimate Bike Path*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?48996) (1992)
[*The 22nd Gear*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/481285.The_22nd_Gear) (1993)

From the [author's blog](http://mikesirota.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/writing-humor-it-doesnt-all-have-to-be-funny/):

> So Jack meets an alien named the Old Guy in downtown San Diego (he’s the only one who can see the alien) and learns that an extra gear has been “installed” on his 21-speed mountain bike, a gear that will allow Jack access to other worlds, dimensions, the past and future, literature, and so on. By the end of six chapters Jack has visited a world of giant talking sea slugs that think he’s a gross-looking life form, and another where, incapacitated, he’s dumped into a cartful of animal manure by a strange little dude who plans on taking him to a witch in order to be cured. There’s a whole lot of silliness in those first fifty or so pages.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I was close, wasn't I? I tried 13th and 19th; I should have kept going. Thank you so much! Now, on to Amazon.